# Upload large size image files from S3 to cloud application through lambda with nodeJS 14

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, axios, s3fs

I'm trying to upload a large image file from S3 to the Cloud application. First I download objects from S3 using aws-sdk for nodejs and then upload them to the cloud application. image is downloaded properly and sent to cloud application only if I increase lambda storage size and time

overcome this how to stream directly from s3 to cloud application without download

[here the flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9AnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Presigned Url with getObject method. It will provide you with a temporary url in order to access your files/images. You won't have to download the image/files to lambda. Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property) for the presigned url

Comment: Hi Rajan
Thanks for your response
But if I use Presigned Url then it sends as a parameter but it should be appended as a file so that in cloud application it will download a file.
here could application is AEM DAM, here it accepts files only